# Updating PHPmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, cpanel

I apologize in advance, because I'm not very well versed on these kind of subjects because I normally work on the front-end part.

I'm now working on a Symfony website (they are using cPanel as well) where one the major bugs is that it stopped sending emails all of a sudden without anyone touching the code. My first thought was that there would have to be a problem with the email service which is PHPmailer. Since they haven't touched the code in about two year, I'm guessing the problem is that PHPmailer is not updated.

Well, now I don't know how to update PHPmailer. I don't know if I can just trade out the old PHPmailer files for the new ones on the cPanel file administrator, or if there is some specific way to do this. Can anybody please help me?

Comment: "without anyone touching the code" - Sounds like your mail subsystem might have had some issues. Check cPanel's (exim) email logs: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/view-email-logs-for-all-emails-sent-received.251631/ You need to find the source by looking at the logs and trying sending mail directly (e.g., process of elimination) before you start swapping out code packages willy-nilly hoping it will help (and not break everything, for real, without doing any good). There are *lots* of potential mail sending/receiving issues *not* related to the code that are more likely. `;)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish Well, I tried looking for the exim_mainlog file on the cPanel File Administrator window, and it doesn't exit, at least by that name :/

Comment: If you're sending through gmail, It's likely that your auth has broken because Google changed theirs (to XOAUTH2) and it has broken many scripts. You need to update to a later PHPMaier (>= 5.2.10) to support it. Whatever it is, you should check your mail and web logs.

Comment: *Something* has obviously changed, so if it isn't the code, then you need to think about what else it could be. What mail provider are you using? Has anything changed with them? (eg @Synchro's comment might be on the right track?) Another possibility: We had a case like this where the mail provider changed their IP address. Our firewall configuration meant that this change caused it to block all our mail. Updating your software is a good idea, even without situations like this, but I'd suggest trying to find the actual source of the issue *before* blindly updating and hoping for the best.

Comment: @Synchro Where can I find that? The file directory in cPanel is so huge I don't even know where to start... Like I said, I'm not well versed in this...
I already looked at cPanel normal and error logs, it doesn't show anything out of the ordinary...

Comment: There are lots of tools for searching on linux - `locate`, `find` etc, don't know about in cpanel though.